# Get data attribute from targeted .on() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having some difficulty with .on() and getting the data-id of a targeted element.

```js
$("#updateTables-0").on(".joinTable").click(function() {

  var tableID = $(".joinTable").attr('data-id');
  console.log(tableID);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <span id='updateTables-0'>
        <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect" >
            <div class="users-list-body">
                <div>
                    <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
                    <p>vs. DeadSaidFred [1500]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="users-list-action">
                    <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #4'>4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect" >
            <div class="users-list-body">
                <div>
                    <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
                    <p>vs. coronatime [1500]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="users-list-action">
                    <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #5'>5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </span>
</ul>
```

As you can see I have two li list items, one with a `data-id` of 2 and one of 3. No matter which one I click, it is only returning the first.

If I was not using `$("#updateTables-0").on()` and just instead had `$(".joinTable")` I could call `$(this)` and it would work perfectly. (Note, using `$(this)` for my actual example above with `.on()` returns `undefined`.)

I am using the `.on()` as the list updates via web sockets, and so I need to have it listening to any changes. Without, once the list updates via the socket, the function won't work at all.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that you have invalid HTML; the ***only*** valid child-element of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` is the `<li>` element; therefore the reasons you're having trouble with JavaScript is just as likely to be the recovery undertaken by the browser to salvage the broken HTML. Why is that `<span>` necessary? Can the event-delegation be placed on the `<ul>` that already wraps the list-items?

Comment: Thanks David, as listed below this was just poor madness when splitting up a <ul> list in to two different php function calls, rather than separating into two different ul's. Not sure what I was thinking at the time... have fixed up. It did not resolve what I already have however, have taken on feedback everyone has provided and used the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use $(this)

Use **jQuery's** inner **$(this)** object inside click callback.

```
$("#updateTables-0 .joinTable").on("click",function() {

   var tableID = $(this).attr('data-id');
   console.log(tableID);

});
```

### Good reading about this topic

https://medium.com/@sak1986/event-binding-in-jquery-daf902be7c58

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned in my question, using $(this) send back undefined, due to the ..on()

Comment: @Taylor1978 well, I edited my answer a little and you can use it with $(this) I tried that in fiddle and it works. On teh other hand, you can still use event.target if you pass event parameter in your callback

Comment: Thank you, I have used your edited solution and working like a charm. Thank you for the topic source too, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As event delegation is required, and your current HTML is invalid – the only valid child of either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element is the `<li>` – I've delegated the event-handling to the parent `<ul>` element (and attached the `id` to that element also). This may need to change for your use-case, however; so please do comment if so.

In this case, however, to stick with the jQuery approach the following code works:

```
// bear in mind that this id now selects the parent <ul>
// we attach the anonymous function as the 'click' event-handler
// of click-events that match the '.joinTable' selector:
$("#updateTables-0").on('click', '.joinTable', function(event) {
  // here we use the 'this' Node (the node we bound the event-
  // handler to, and retrieve its 'data-id' attribute value
  // with the data() method:
  const tableID = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(tableID);
});
```

```js
$("#updateTables-0").on('click', '.joinTable', function() {
  const tableID = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(tableID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='updateTables-0'>
  <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
    <div class="users-list-body">
      <div>
        <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
        <p>vs. DeadSaidFred [1500]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list-action">
        <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #4'>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
    <div class="users-list-body">
      <div>
        <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
        <p>vs. coronatime [1500]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list-action">
        <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #5'>5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This can, as can *all* jQuery approaches, be rewritten into plain native JavaScript:

```
// here we use document.querySelector() to retrieve the
// HTMLElement Node that matches the CSS selector:
const delegationTarget = document.querySelector('#updateTables-0');

// here we use addEventListener() to bind the anonymous
// Arrow function as the event-handler for the 'click'
// event:
delegationTarget.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  // using evt.target to find the element upon which
  // the click event was initially fired; using
  // closest() to navigate to the ancestor <li>
  // of that clicked-element; and using the
  // HTMLElement.dataset API to recover the attribute-
  // value of the 'id' property (or to recover the
  // attribute-value of the data-id attribute, if you
  // prefer):
  const tableID = evt.target.closest('li').dataset.id;
  console.log(tableID);
});
```

```js
const delegationTarget = document.querySelector('#updateTables-0');

delegationTarget.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const tableID = evt.target.closest('li').dataset.id;
  console.log(tableID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='updateTables-0'>
  <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
    <div class="users-list-body">
      <div>
        <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
        <p>vs. DeadSaidFred [1500]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list-action">
        <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #4'>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
    <div class="users-list-body">
      <div>
        <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
        <p>vs. coronatime [1500]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list-action">
        <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #5'>5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- HTML:
- [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).
- [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).
- [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).
- JavaScript:
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Event` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
- jQuery:
- [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you. The original layout was calling on one <ul> but I was calling two different PHP functions and somehow in my madness kept them in the same <ul> and added two different span id's.. crazy. Thanks for the pick up. Have corrected. I have used Jakub's solution below which is similar to your jQuery response. 

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Taylor, you're very welcome indeed. If you've chosen to use one of the answers here, though, consider accepting that answer, this allows the system to 'know' that the question has been answered, and mark it appropriately. It also gives 15 reputation points to the person whose answer you accept, and gives 2 points to you. :)

Comment: Thanks David... as a first time user I was about to ask, 'Accept answer? Where is that?!' but then I found the tick. Appreciate your guidance :)

Comment: @Taylor: my apologies, when I began writing that comment I saw that you were a new user, and I know I meant to tell you how to accept and answer, but clearly I was tired and forgot. But kudos on working it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `<span>` as a direct child element of the `<ul>`, this is invalid HTML. To fix this, you could assign the `id` directly to the `<ul>` element:

```
  <ul id='updateTables-0'>
    <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
      <div class="users-list-body">
        <div>
          <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
          <p>vs. DeadSaidFred [1500]</p>
        </div>
        <div class="users-list-action">
          <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #4'>4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
      <div class="users-list-body">
        <div>
          <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
          <p>vs. coronatime [1500]</p>
        </div>
        <div class="users-list-action">
          <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #5'>5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And then use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to capture each `<li>` of the unordered list:

```js
$("#updateTables-0").on("click", "li", function() {
  const $li = $(this)
  console.log(`data-id of list item: ${ $li.attr('data-id') }`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='updateTables-0'>
  <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
    <div class="users-list-body">
      <div>
        <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
        <p>vs. DeadSaidFred [1500]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list-action">
        <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #4'>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item joinTable" data-id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tableConnect">
    <div class="users-list-body">
      <div>
        <h5 class="text-primary">100 pt | Regular</h5>
        <p>vs. coronatime [1500]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list-action">
        <div class="new-message-count" title='Table #5'>5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```